# How to display the content of time log in the WPF ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been searching for answers but I haven't found one really.
I know the logic but I just don't have the idea how to implement it.

This is my time log:

```
No    Mchn  EnNo        Name        Mode    IOMd    DateTime    
00001   1   00001234                1   0   2004/01/01  01:01
00002   1   00001234                1   0   2015/05/12  04:01
00003   1   00001234                2   0   2015/05/12  04:01
00004   1   00001234                1   0   2004/01/01  01:01
00005   1   00001234                1   0   2015/05/13  10:42
```

and I want to convert this into a listview.
Really need your help.

Comment: What do you mean "convert this into a listview"? Do you need to display it in a ListView?

Comment: In which mvc, webform, winform, or wpf...

Comment: @ kulaeff, yes, i need to display it in a ListView

Comment: @hungndv, this is in C# WPF

Comment: Read data from log file. Parse them in to LogEntity list. LogEntity is a class which have properties such as No, Mchn, EnNo, Name... Then binding them in wpf listview. That's all.

Comment: @hungndv, did I use the right code?

Comment: @Adriano Hernandez III: I think you should have learning curve at programming. Your problem is a basic program that every coder can easy write. So try to learn hard. Happy. :)

Answer (score 0):

For each entry create a class, something like this

```
internal class TimeLogEntryViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Mchn { get; set; }
    public string EnNo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Mode { get; set; }
    public string IOMd { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

(Just correct the names and types of properties).

Then you need to bind the collection of such entries to the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView`, and create a custom `DataTemplate` to display each entry. You can get some ideas in [this tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/).

If really need to display it as a grid, then consider using `GridView` instead.

**UPDATE**

Don't create and add list view items in the code behind of your view. In WPF you should follow the MVVM pattern. You can get started from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial).

Comment: thanks for the help. but i just edited my post. is it correct to use it? thank you.

Comment: so i must create a database, and a table contaning the class that you said?

Comment: @Adriano Hernandez It is not necessary to create a class. Your approach is pretty good though it is not "pro".

Comment: Yes I'm not a pro. HAHAH. I'm only a beginner. 
What I wanna do really, is import a text file, and display it into a listview, and then there save it into my TimeLog table.

Answer (score 0):

now i worked on the codes and i came up with this,

namespace textfile
{

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void LoadButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(@"GLG_001.TXT"))
            ListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(line));
    }


    }

}
```

but an error occurred. it says, Error   1   'System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments    D:\Documents\Desktop\textfile\textfile\MainWindow.xaml.cs   33  36  textfile

Comment: `ListViewItem` has only one constructor which doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: I'm only a beginner here. I'm sorry but can you pls give me the exact code you're talking about? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

```
namespace textfile
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void LoadButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(@"GLG_001.TXT"))
            {
                var listViewItem = new ListViewItem();
                listViewItem.Content = line;

                ListView.Items.Add(listViewItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It says it cant find the part of the directory. But I'm 100% sure my path is correct.

Could not find a part of the path 'D:\\Documents\\Desktop\\textfile\\textfile\\bin\\Debug\\TimeLog\\GLG_001.txt'."}